# Unable to connect to the MKS: Failed to connect to server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:902, the port is closed

Tags: port, esxi

I have a server with Vsphere ESXi 5.5. when i try to start a virtual machine with the vsphere client i get this error:

```
Unable to connect to the MKS: Failed to connect to server 172.16.63.3:902
```

and nothing happen. i have tried to nmap the ip but only three port are opened:

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-07-22 17:00 CEST
Strange error from connect (22):Invalid argument
Nmap scan report for 172.16.63.3
Host is up (0.00034s latency).
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https
```

how can i open that port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution for this problem:
http://mediarealm.com.au/articles/2013/01/vmware-vsphere-remote-access-via-ssh-tunnel/

Answer (score -1):

I login ssh of vcenter server and login into esxi server from vcenter server ssh login (Remark:First You should open esxi shell in esxi server after installation).
And ping to my local computer. After that it's ok now.

Comment: Maybe I need more coffee, but I'm having a hard time following this.  Any way to explain this more clearly?  Thanks.